# Serve static file from different server express.js

Tags: node.js, express

How to serve static file e.g index.html from different server

app.use(express.static('http://example.com/'))

Comment: Why would you not just set the source of the file to the external server? Is this an image? CSS? or?

Comment: Its html page, i want to show data sent by express server to html page that i serve from different location

Comment: You could use an iFrame to do that. If you need to pass information to the external page, you can use querystring parameters.

Answer (score 1):

A proxy such as `http-proxy-middleware` can do this:

```
var express = require('express');
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

var app = express();

app.use('/api', proxy({target: 'http://www.example.org', changeOrigin: true}));
app.listen(3000);

// http://localhost:3000/api/foo/bar -> http://www.example.org/api/foo/bar
```

see https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware